# What are Abyssal and Infernal called after the Remaster?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, languages

My character spoke Abyssal, but it is not available in Foundry after the Remaster. There is a table in the Remaster Core Preview document with the old and new names for the languages, but I do not see Abyssal there:

| Old | New | Element or Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aquan | Thalassic | Water |
| Auran | Susurran | Air |
| Ignan | Pyric | Fire |
| Terran | Petran | Earth |
| Abyssal | ? | The Outer Rifts (formerly known as Abyss) |
| Infernal | ? | Hell? (formerly known as Nine Hells) |

(Also, is the Nine Hells now just Hell?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Chthonian and Diabolic, Respectively

In Foundry with the Pathfinder 2e system this can be viewed under Game Settings->Remaster Changes->2. Rules and Languages, which I've copied below and seems current to what's available in the Player Core.

### Languages

Several languages have been renamed.

- Abyssal is now Chthonian.
- Aquan is now Thalassic.
- Auran is now Sussuran.
- Celestial is now Empyrean.
- Druidic is now Wildsong.
- Gnoll is now Kholo.
- Ignan is now Pyric.
- Infernal is now Diabolic.
- Sylvan is now Fey.
- Terran is now Petran.
- Undercommon is now Sakvroth.